# product filter sortby highest or lowest using javascript/vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**I have data like this:**

```
> Price : ["800000","989000","780000","349000"]
```

if the user chooses sort by lowest price, I want the data displayed to be composed of the lowest price to the highest price like this:

```
> Price : ["349000","780000","800000","989000"]
```

on this issue if the user chooses sort by highest price it works but when choosing sort by lowest price the data is not arranged correctly

**Result :**

```
> Price : ["800000","989000","780000","349000"]
```

**I am using vue.js**

```
<p><strong>Sort By:</strong> <select v-model="sortBy">
  <option value="highestprice">Highest Price</option>
  <option value="lowestprice">Lowest Price</option>
  <option value="newestproduct">Newest Product</option>
  <option value="oldestproduct">Oldest Product</option>
</select>
</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      const product_list = new Vue({
        el:"#product-list",
        data:{
          filterBox:false,
          color:[],
          sortBy: null,
          productType:[],
          dataFilter:{
            soryBy:"",
            base_color:[],
            category:[]
          },
           isActive: false,
           products:{!! $products->toJson() !!},
           productcolors:{!!$productcolors->toJson()!!},
           categories:{!!$categories->toJson()!!},
           inputSearch:'',
        },
      computed:{
              filteredProduct:function(){
                return this.products.filter((product) => {
                  return (this.inputSearch.length === 0 || product.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.inputSearch.toLowerCase())
                  || product.category.toLowerCase().includes(this.inputSearch.toLowerCase())
                  || product.base_color.toLowerCase().includes(this.inputSearch.toLowerCase())
                  || product.product_code.toLowerCase().includes(this.inputSearch.toLowerCase()) ) &&
                  (this.color.length === 0 || this.color.includes(product.base_color)) &&
                  (this.productType.length === 0 || this.productType.includes(product.category))
                }).sort((a, b) => {
                            if (this.sortBy =='highestprice') {
                            return b.price-a.price;
                            }
                            else if (this.sortyBy =='lowestprice') {
                            return a.price-b.price;
                            }
                            else if(this.sortBy =='oldestproduct'){
                            return b.id-a.id;
                            }
                            else if(this.sortBy =='newestproduct'){
                                return a.id-b.id;
                            }

                          });

              }

            }
```

what's wrong with this code? how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your code...

```
else if (this.sortyBy =='lowestprice') {
```

->

```
else if (this.sortBy =='lowestprice') {
```